# C++ error: How to solve malloc: *** error for object ... pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, malloc

Why am I getting this error after I compile:

Program1(49296,0x7fff74b72000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9222500040: pointer being freed was not allocated

Is there a way to resolve it?  I only get it when I do recursion, but if I take out this line:

```
if(counter == G.nameSet.size())
{  
  explore(G, *adjPtr);
}
```

...It then works

```
void explore(Graph & G, Node & foo)
{
  G.nameSet.insert(foo.name());
  set <string> tempNameSet;

  list <Node> adjacentList = G.getAdjNodes(foo); 

  int y = adjacentList.size();
  list<Node>::iterator adjPtr = adjacentList.begin();

  for(int i=0; i < y;  i++ )
  {
tempNameSet = G.nameSet;

set<string>::iterator nSetPtr = G.nameSet.begin();
int counter = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < G.nameSet.size(); j++)
{ 
  if(*nSetPtr != adjPtr->name())
    counter++; 

  if(tempNameSet.size() > 1)
    nSetPtr  = tempNameSet.erase(nSetPtr);
}

if(counter == G.nameSet.size())
{  
  explore(G, *adjPtr);  //even when I plug in foo instead of *adjPtr, i get the same error
}

if(adjacentList.size() > 1)
  adjPtr  = adjacentList.erase(adjPtr);

  }
}
```

Comment: You get this error because there's a bug in your code. Unfortunately, your question fails to meet the requirement of providing a [mcve]; as such an asnwer will be highly unlikely. You need to edit your question, and replace the randomly-selected chunks of code it currently contains with a concise, compact, [mcve].

Comment: Alright Sam, just did

Comment: `nSetPtr` is initialized with an iterator into `G.nameSet`, but you pass it to `tempNameSet.erase`. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: There's still a lot of function calls to unknown code. Please study how to perform debugging on your code, and then come back and report the exact line where your message appears/

Comment: Fixed your title. You don't 'manage' this. You *solve the problem* that caused it. You shouldn't be calling either `malloc()` or `free()` in a C++ program.

Comment: No, this question still fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. "Complete" means that anyone can compile and reproduce the issue. This doesn't mean that you get to dump the entire source code into the question, because this will violate the "Minimum" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard because that function isn't calling free directly. At a guess, it's crashing in erase(adjPtr). To verify that is the case, put a diagnostic printf before and after the call, and the crash should happen between the calls. Probably adjPtr is going empty and that causes erase to fail, but exactly where the logic error is is quite hard to tell.